# Find the domain and the solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to understand the solution of this problem.

$$
\dfrac{(2x-8)}{(x+5)} \leq0
$$

The domain is $ \mathbb{R}\ - \{-5\}$ and the solution is $-5 \lt x \leq 4
$
However, I can't figure why $-5$ is not included in the solution. I did a table of sign :

```
x | -10 | -5 | 0 | 4 | 10
  |   + |  0 | - | E | +
```

It is "$\leq 0$" so I select everything that is smaller or equals to 0...

$x=-5, 2*-5-8/-5+5 = 0 .. 0$ is equal to $0$, why is it excluded in the solution ?

Thanks !

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23451/how-to-find-the-solution-for-frac2x-3x1-leq-1

Comment: You cannot divide by zero.

Comment: What is the E in your sign table?  Shouldn't it be 0?

Comment: Have you tried drawing a graph of your function?

Comment: In the table, the entry for $x=-5$ should not say $0$, it should say something ND (not defined), or E, which is what my calculator says. And the entry for $x=4$ should be $0$. Maybe you just transposed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the equation $$\dfrac{(2x-8)}{(x+5)} \leq0$$ if you put $x = -5$ it reduces to $$ \frac{-18}{0} \le 0$$  as the denominator is zero the left side of this inequality is known as  [division by zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero).From the same Wikipedia url :

> Whether this expression can be assigned a well-defined value depends
>   upon the mathematical setting. In ordinary (real number) arithmetic,
>   the expression has no meaning, as there is no number which, multiplied
>   by 0, gives a (a≠0).

So as we are dealing with real number arithmetic here we are excluding $x=-5$ from the domain.

Coming to the solution, $$\dfrac{(2x-8)}{(x+5)} \leq0 \Rightarrow (2x-8) \leq0\Rightarrow x \leq 4 $$ only if we assume $(x+5) \neq 0$,but then either $(x+5) \gt 0$ or $(x+5) \lt 0$.

But  when $(x+5) \lt 0$,multiplying will reverse the inequality giving  $(2x-8) \geq0 $ hence,$x \lt -5$ and $x \ge 4$  which makes no sense,hence discarded.

So the only possible solution is when $x \gt -5$ and $x \lt 4$ i,e. $-5 \lt x \le 4$